# Export datatable with images to PDF

Tags: html, r, shiny, dt

I'm trying to create a Shiny app that generates two tables side-by-side (or one scrollable table with the first column always showing). The first table will contain a picture of a house, with some key characteristics (size, age etc.) The second table will be a scrollable table showing one or more similar houses with pictures and characteristics.

My ultimate goal is for a user to be able to select/deselect the similar houses that they want to see and then export them as a pdf or similar. Ideally this would work with any number of selected homes by using multiple pages (with the main house on each) if there are too many to fit on one page, e.g.

[image: Multi-page example]

I have the first part of the app working using datatables. My question is how do you export datatables without losing the images? Preferably I would be able to export the two tables side by side as described above. Is this possible? Is there a better way to do it? Here's a reproducible toy example of what I have so far:

UI

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Tables to export"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      downloadButton('export')
    ),

    # Show tables
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(3, DT::dataTableOutput('t1')),  
        column(9,style="overflow-x:scroll;",DT::dataTableOutput('t2'))
      )
    )
  )
))
```

Server

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(DT)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  p1 <- '<img src="http://www.dailyexcelsior.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/house.jpg" width=150 height=100>'
  p2 <- '<img src="http://www.pd.co.th/uploads/content/2017/10/o_1brg6i1m25is1hnng571876544a.jpg" width=150 height=100>'
  p3 <- '<img src="https://www.harronhomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Birkwith-330x192-24-June-EDIT1.jpg" width=150 height=100>'
  p4 <- '<img src="https://m.persimmonhomes.com/images/the-rockcliff_133414.jpg" width=150 height=100>'
  p5 <- '<img src="https://www.ryanhomes.com/rh-community-gallery-NewAspectRatio/d8b0c394-b123-4d9d-957b-1d24e21d319f/db/d8b0c394-b123-4d9d-957b-1d24e21d319f.jpg" width=150 height=100>'
  p6 <- '<img src="https://www.iconichouses.org/foto/houses/duldeck.jpg" width=150 height=100>'

  t1 <- datatable(t(data.frame("Pic"=p1,Size=1500,Age=5,Bathrooms=2,row.names="p1")), 
                  escape = F, options = list(dom = 't',pageLength = 20))

  t2 <- datatable(t(data.frame("Pic"=c(p2,p3,p4,p5,p6),Size=c(1500,1200,1400,1600,1300),Age=c(5,15,10,7,12),Bathrooms=c(1.5,2,2,1.5,2),
                         row.names=c("p2","p3","p4","p5","p6"))), 
            escape = F, options = list(dom = 't',pageLength = 20,width="100%") )

  output$t1 <-  renderDataTable(t1)

  output$t2 <- renderDataTable(t2)

  output$export = downloadHandler(
    filename = "plots.pdf",#function() {"plots.pdf"},
    content = function(file) {
      pdf(file, onefile = TRUE)
      # Something here???
      dev.off()
    }
  )
})
```

Comment: One alternative might be to create a separate knitr/rmarkdown report that's run in the background when the user clicks download. See [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/download-knitr-reports.html) example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save a datatable to a html file with `saveWidget` (in the `htmlwidget` package, but it is imported in `DT`), and take a pdf snapshot with `webshot::webshot`:

```
library(DT)
library(webshot)

p2 <- '<img src="http://www.pd.co.th/uploads/content/2017/10/o_1brg6i1m25is1hnng571876544a.jpg" width=150 height=100>'
p3 <- '<img src="https://www.harronhomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Birkwith-330x192-24-June-EDIT1.jpg" width=150 height=100>'
p4 <- '<img src="https://m.persimmonhomes.com/images/the-rockcliff_133414.jpg" width=150 height=100>'
p5 <- '<img src="https://www.ryanhomes.com/rh-community-gallery-NewAspectRatio/d8b0c394-b123-4d9d-957b-1d24e21d319f/db/d8b0c394-b123-4d9d-957b-1d24e21d319f.jpg" width=150 height=100>'
p6 <- '<img src="https://www.iconichouses.org/foto/houses/duldeck.jpg" width=150 height=100>'

dtable <- datatable(
  t(data.frame(
    Pic = c(p2,p3,p4,p5,p6), 
    Size = c(1500,1200,1400,1600,1300), 
    Age = c(5,15,10,7,12), 
    Bathrooms = c(1.5,2,2,1.5,2),
    row.names = c("p2","p3","p4","p5","p6"))), 
  escape = FALSE, 
  options = list(
    dom = 't', 
    pageLength = 20, 
    width = "100%")
)

html <- "dtable.html"
saveWidget(dtable, html)
webshot(html, "dtableSnapshot.pdf")
```

[image]

For two tables, you can use the `xml2` package to insert the second table in the html file of the first table:

```
p1 <- '<img src="http://www.dailyexcelsior.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/house.jpg" width=150 height=100>'
p2 <- '<img src="http://www.pd.co.th/uploads/content/2017/10/o_1brg6i1m25is1hnng571876544a.jpg" width=150 height=100>'
p3 <- '<img src="https://www.harronhomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Birkwith-330x192-24-June-EDIT1.jpg" width=150 height=100>'
p4 <- '<img src="https://m.persimmonhomes.com/images/the-rockcliff_133414.jpg" width=150 height=100>'
p5 <- '<img src="https://www.ryanhomes.com/rh-community-gallery-NewAspectRatio/d8b0c394-b123-4d9d-957b-1d24e21d319f/db/d8b0c394-b123-4d9d-957b-1d24e21d319f.jpg" width=150 height=100>'
p6 <- '<img src="https://www.iconichouses.org/foto/houses/duldeck.jpg" width=150 height=100>'

dtable1 <- datatable(
  t(data.frame(
    "Pic" = p1, 
    Size = 1500, 
    Age = 5, 
    Bathrooms = 2, 
    row.names = "p1")), 
  escape = FALSE, 
  height = 300,
  options = list(
    dom = 't', 
    pageLength = 20)
)

dtable2 <- datatable(
  t(data.frame(
    Pic = c(p2,p3,p4,p5,p6), 
    Size = c(1500,1200,1400,1600,1300), 
    Age = c(5,15,10,7,12), 
    Bathrooms = c(1.5,2,2,1.5,2),
    row.names = c("p2","p3","p4","p5","p6"))), 
  escape = FALSE, 
  options = list(
    dom = 't', 
    pageLength = 20)
)

# save tables as html
saveWidget(dtable1, "dtable1.html")
saveWidget(dtable2, "dtable2.html", selfcontained = FALSE)

# read the html files in R lists
library(xml2)
list1 <- as_list(read_html("dtable1.html"))
list2 <- as_list(read_html("dtable2.html"))
div2 <- list2$html$body$div[1:3]
scripts2 <- list2$html$body[4:5]

# # change default style "width:960px;height:500px;"
# # that doesn't work, actually the dimensions are set by JavaScript
# # => use the width/height options of datatable()
# attr(list1$html$body$div$div, "style") <- attr(div2$div, "style") <- "width: 100%;"

# "stack" the two datatables
list12 <- list1
list12$html$body$div <- c(list12$html$body$div, div2)
list12$html$body <- c(list12$html$body, scripts2)

# set the attributes because they are lost
attr(list12$html$body$div, "id") <- "htmlwidget_container"
attr(list12$html$body, "style") <- attr(list1$html$body, "style")

# create new html file
html12 <- as_xml_document(list12)
write_html(html12, "dtables.html", options = "as_html")

# snapshot
webshot("dtables.html", "dtablesSnapshot.pdf")
```

[image]